# Core graphics and UIKit interaction

Tags: uikit, core-animation, core-graphics, rotation, user-interaction

Hey all, I'm am trying to make a very interactive UI with lots of animations and effects.

But I don't know if:

1. Core graphics can support user interaction (touches, drags, etc)
2. Core graphics supports object rotation
3. Core graphics can interact with UIKit and Core Animation in any way

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about iPhone not Mac (because of mention of touches).

1) CoreGraphics is mostly associated with drawing of images. User interaction is via your view and the touches* member functions. Within the view's drawRect function, you can use CoreGraphics to do custom drawing.

2) Yes, you can get rotation, but easiest way is to set the transform property using a CGAffineTransformMakeRotation. Drop down to the layer and you can even use 3d transforms (which is I think how they do stuff like cover flow).

3) See #1.